# Asp.net regular expression validator

Tags: asp.net, regex

I've two required fields on my form which I have made required using a required field validator.

I'm also looking to make the two text boxes only accept numeric input. Textbox 1 must be 7 digits only and textbox 2 has to be 6 digits only .

What would be the regular expressions for these?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

7 digits: `^\d{7}$`

6 digits: `^\d{6}$`